# How to reset the weights of TF-Agents DDQN Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-agent

Assume that you have successfully trained a DDQN agent for a number of iterations in TF-Agents. Now, you need to reset the neural network weights (of the Q-Network; apparently) to the form it was initialized to and continue the training from there (nothing else is changed). How can I do that in TF-Agents?